# Reorganizing dataframe in R

Tags: r

I am trying to manipulate this data frame:

```
df
   name     date     X  Y
Person1   Monday     1  5
Person2   Monday     2  6
Person1  Tuesday     3  7
Person2  Tuesday     4  8
```

To look like this:

```
   name   variable  Monday  Tuesday
Person1          X       1        3
Person1          Y       5        7
Person2          X       2        4
Person2          Y       6        8
```

Is there a way to manipulate my original data frame to get this result using R?

This was marked as a duplicate, but neither of the links provided solved my problem because I am not quite going from wide to long or long to wide.

Comment: This was marked as a duplicate, but neither of the links provided solved my problem because I am not quite going from wide to long or long to wide.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dt <- fread(text)
dcast(melt(dt, id.vars = c('name', 'date')), name + variable ~ date)
#      name variable Monday Tuesday
#1: Person1        X      1       3
#2: Person1        Y      5       7
#3: Person2        X      2       4
#4: Person2        Y      6       8
```

**data**

```
text <- "name    | date    | X | Y
Person1 | Monday  | 1 | 5
Person2 | Monday  | 2 | 6
Person1 | Tuesday | 3 | 7
Person2 | Tuesday | 4 | 8"

text <- gsub("\\|", "", text)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, then check out [R For Data Science](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/transform.html) for more details

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  gather(X, Y, key = variable, value = temp) %>% 
  spread(key = date, value = temp)
```